# How to set screen resolution and density in /system/build.prop?

Tags: android-x86

I want to automate the creation of virtual android devices (using Android x86 and QEMU/KVM on Linux), the device settings includes screen resolution and density. The common way to set these settings is through `adb shell wm size` and `adb shell wm density` but it requires the device to be running, while changing `/system/build.prop` doesn't, I can mount the virtual disk and make changes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are open to modifying virtual disk you can edit the file `settings_global.xml` located under `/data/system/users/0/` directory. Among other things, look for these two keys in that file:

- `display_size_forced`
- `display_density_forced`

These keys correspond to `wm size WxH` and `wm density DPI` respectively. Change their values to your desirable `WidthxHeight` and `density`.

Save it. That's it.